# Cox Regression on multiple imputed datasets (R)

Tags: survival, multiple-imputation, pooling

I fit a cox regression using the coxph function of the survival package. Now I wanted to do the same on a multiple imputed data set (which I already have, generated in another software). I found some ways to do this by using a single dataset with aggregated values. However, in my understanding, I should not use aggregated values but rather calculate and pool the estimates using Rubin's rules. Is there a way to do this in R with data sets not generated by mice etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @David answer, but I'll add something.

I add the option of [this](https://nerler.github.io/EP16_Multiple_Imputation/practical/08_Imputation_of_Survival_Data.html#Preface) R tutorial on survival data imputation, which might help you in the implementation of imputation of survival data, if that will be your way to go. However, I am not sure the procedures in the tutorial account for the substantive model analogously to the paper he mentions (that would be interesting to deepen).

On the other hand, in case your data do not carry the complexities mentioned in @David answer, I include a sample code you can use for your survival analysis when you have a list of imputed dataset.

```
#PACKAGES
library(survival)
#library(parallel)

#DATA
origdat<-#Original non-imputed variables (you might have columns that weren't imputed 
#and were not used in the imputation process as predictors,
#such as the treatment variable)
impdat<-#list of imputed datasets

#
#REGRESSION MODELS
#
#IF YOU ONLY NEED TO MODEL THE DATA FROM IMPUTED DATASETS
est <- lapply(impdat, function(x) { 
  mod <- coxph(your_frml, data=x)
  list(coef=coef(mod), vcov=vcov(mod))
})

#####################################
#IF YOU NEED TO MERGE IMPUTED AND NOT IMPUTED DATA
#est <- lapply(impdat, function(x) { 
#  data <- merge(tdat, x)
#  mod <- coxph(your_frml, data=data)
#  list(coef=coef(mod), vcov=vcov(mod))
#})

#PARALLEL VERSION
# cl <- makeCluster(spec = number_of_cores)
# clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("tdat"))
# est <- parLapply(cl,impdat, function(x) { 
#       library(survival);
#       data <- merge(tdat, x)
#       mod <- coxph(your_frml, data=data)
#       list(coef=coef(mod), vcov=vcov(mod))
#       })
# stopCluster(cl)
#####################################

# COMBINE THE ESTIMATES USING RUBIN'S RULE
coef <- lapply(est, "[[", "coef")
vcov <- lapply(est, "[[", "vcov")
poolpar <- frubin(coef, vcov)
```

where the function `frubin` is defined as:

```
# ARGUMENTS:
# - COEF: LIST OF COEFFICIENTS FROM FITTED MODELS
# - VCOV: LIST OF (CO)VARIANCE MATRICES FROM THE FITTED MODELS
# SEE DOI:10.1186/1471-2288-9-57 FOR ALGEBRAIC DEFINITIONS AND REFERENCES
frubin <- function(coef, vcov) {
  
  # PARAMETERS
  m <- length(coef)
  k <- length(coef[[1]])
  
  # AVERAGE COEF
  coefmat <- Reduce(rbind, coef)
  coefavg <- colMeans(coefmat)
  
  # WITHIN, BETWEEN, AND TOTAL VCOV 
  vcovwith <- Reduce("+", vcov) / m
  vcovbetw <- cov(coefmat)
  vcovtot <- vcovwith + (1+1/m)*vcovbetw
  
  # RETURN
  list(coef=coefavg, vcov=vcovtot)
}
```

Of course the code needs to be adjusted to your case.

**Update:** In my code, I made the additional assumption that you have some other data that did not require imputation and I didn't want to be part of the imputation process. For example, this column could represent the value of a specific treatment/exposure you want to see the effect of. I did this because it's something that happens often in epidemiological studies (e.g. effects of air pollution on mortality), in which we might have complete treatment/exposure history (e.g. air pollution measurement from fixed urban monitors) but some confounders/covariates contain missings due to several reasons (e.g. study participants felt uncomfortable providing information about their income, which is considered a confounder, as a proxy of socio-economic deprivation at area level. Do not worry if it's not clear, it's just an example).

So, in this case, you would have to merge the exposure data and the imputed confounders (income, education level, age, etc.) and run the model on this dataset. I hope it's clear but ask questions if needed.

The `lapply()` code runs like `with()` but it explicitly extracts the information (coefficients and variances) you need to apply the Rubin's rule. However, you cannot use these information directly in `pool()` (because it needs a specific object class called `mira`, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.15.0/topics/pool)), so the `frubin()` comes to do the job.

In other words, this script includes a procedure to pool estimates from models of imputed data using base R and it's quite customizable for different needs, instead of relying on the `mice` package.

The results are the pooled coefficients and standard deviations. If you need to extract the Hazard Ratios, you can use this:

```
y  <- poolpar$coef + outer(poolpar$vcov, c(0, -1.96, 1.96), '*')
hr <- exp(y)
```

**Update 2:** I modified a bit the code, so now you can run it *without* using the non-imputed dataset. Of course, you don't have to use it if you used `as.mids()` and it worked well, but I'll leave the code here so others can also have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Tbh, I don't quite get the code you posted. In the tutorial, however, there are only 2 lines:

`micesurv_mira <- with(micesurv, coxph(Surv(time = time, event) ~ platelet +
                                        age + sex + chol + stage))`

`summary(pool(micesurv_mira), conf.int = TRUE)`

This works out. If I exp() the estimate, I get the HR, right? Is it really that easy to get the combined estimate? What would be the difference to your code?

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Both `mitools::imputationList()` and `mice::as.mids()` can work with externally imputed datasets. There are probably also other options. However, see Bartlett et al (2014), https://doi.org/10.1177/0962280214521348, for issues related to imputation in non-linear models like the Cox model. A naive FCS imputation procedure may give biased results.